# POSIX select() generates CPU load

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix

We are using `select()` to monitor TCP/IP Sockets, which generally works fine in our Linux-program. Timeout is 10s.
However, we realized that after being detached (e.g. via `nohup`) our process generates 100% CPU load. We tracked it down to occur at select() (which is called in loop). `nfds` and our `fd_set` seem to be normal. As already mentioned, timeout is 10s. The values of the arguments were double checked (Tracelog/timer vs. `strace`).

If the process is being detached due to termination of its parent process (which is the default use case), a keyboard stroke (of any key) in the same bash causes the process to generate 100% CPU load (which is then maintained forever). If I start our program directly in nohup, the load is 100% from beginning on.

`select()` is known to generate high CPU load if anything is wrong with the socket, which is not the case here.

Has anybody else ever figured out such kind of problem?

Comment: What does `select` return? Which file descriptors do you pass to `select`?

Comment: @MagnusHoff Output of strace: `select(8, [7], NULL, NULL, {10, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)`. We are using only the readfds, while the value of 7 corresponds to our TCP/IP Socket. During this high CPU phase, `select` always returns 0 (which is fine because there are no connected Sockets)

Comment: You have already got two close votes for the lack of  [mcve].  Can you please spend the time to reduce the program to a minimum, and include the code here.